# Using web socket with Tomcat 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, websocket, tomcat7

I would like to use web socket, and I started looking to do so with tomcat API. I'm currently using Tomcat 7.0.37.

I tried to follow the example code from tomcat [documentation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet.java?revision=1354477&view=markup).

I'm also using maven for the project, so I added this to my *pom.xml* :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.39</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

First thing that's weird, I get an error message in Eclipse for this line :

```java
private class MyMessageInbound extends MessageInbound
```

The error message is "*The hierarchy of the type MyMessageInbound is inconsistent*", but I'm still able to compile and launch the webapp.

I also added the configuration in the *web.xml* as follow:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>wsChat</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>websocket.chat.ChatWebSocketServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wsChat</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/websocket/chat</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, I'm able to launch the webapp, but when I go to the chat page, I get an error on the chat board saying "*Info: WebSocket closed.*". Tomcat log give me the following message:

```java
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [wsChat] in context with path [/websocket-tuto] threw exception [L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: websocket.chat.ChatWebSocketServlet$MyMessageInbound.<init>(Lwebsocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet;Luwebsocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet$MyMessageInbound;)V
at websocket.chat.ChatWebSocketServlet.createWebSocketInbound(ChatWebSocketServlet.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.doGet(WebSocketServlet.java:121)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think the only missing information here is the source of the [chat page](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/websocket/chat.html?revision=1351055&view=markup).

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong ??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the issue !

I tried to package the project with Maven on command line, and get this error:

```java
[ERROR] class file for org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeInbound not found
```

From this, I just added the following to the *pom.xml*:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.39</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I hope this will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your inherited class MessageInbound implementing the Servlet interface? Can you provide the doGet implementation of your ChatWebSocketServlet or the MessageInbound class? Sorry man, your information is incomplete at all...

Comment: The whole class is provided in the first [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/chat/ChatWebSocketServlet.java?revision=1354477&view=markup) of the first post. And that's maybe not clear in my last post, but the problem is solved ;)

Comment: Thats good to hear. Please post your success story as well. Guess you had permission issues with Tomcat and WebSockets right?