# Vaadin 8 (8.1.5) - Push error running on Tomcat 7 (7.0.82)

Tags: java, tomcat7, vaadin

I am trying to configure Vaadin Push on my actual Vaadin application, but when I just add the needed configuration to make it work in the web.xml, the server started throwing the error above:

```
Jan 17, 2018 10:06:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invokeSEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SurabayaUIServlet] in context with path threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeInbound
           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
           at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:58)
           at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2284)
           at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.handleRequest(PushRequestHandler.java:244)
           at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.handleSessionExpired(PushRequestHandler.java:278)
           at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleSessionExpired(VaadinService.java:1672)
           at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1578)
           at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:381)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Follow the servlet configuration:

```
<servlet>   
<servlet-name>UIServlet</servlet-name>   
<servlet-class>com.wro.vaadinapp.v2.UIServlet</servlet-class>   
<init-param>     
     <param-name>UI</param-name> 
     <param-value>com.wro.vaadinapp.v2.MyUI</param-value>   
</init-param>   
<init-param>
      <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.asyncSupport</param-name>
      <param-value>org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket</param-value>   
</init-param>   
<init-param>
      <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
      <param-value>AppWidgetset</param-value>   
</init-param>   
<init-param> 
     <param-name>pushmode</param-name>
      <param-value>automatic</param-value>   
</init-param>   
<async-supported>true</async-supported> 
</servlet>
```

and my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>          
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId> 
    <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat7</artifactId>                                                    
    <version>2.0.1</version>          
</dependency>           
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>           
</dependency>           
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>           
</dependency>          
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>        
</dependency>
```

This project was working until now without the push and with these configs it runs but keeps throwing this exception every 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the same Vaadin/Tomcat versions (using NIO connector) and the UI was propertly pushed. The only difference is that I had to use VaadinServlet since I don't know what is in your custom servlet.

Comment: @javier can you post your project configuration, please? I've tried to apply the configs described in the Vaadin Oficial Docs but it is still not working properly.

Comment: It's a verbatim copy of your example... Can you upload a MCVE to github? I would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Does answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857239/using-web-socket-with-tomcat-7 solve your problem as well?

Comment: Sorry for been out for so long. @Javier I can't share this project in github because it is a private code.

Comment: @Mika I didn't have tried this solution yet, but I will try and then I'll post the result here!